# Symbol not found: _PyBuffer_Type error with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

So I am working on a Python project in PyCharm on the Mac, and went to rename the project. When I did so, I began running into this issue: When I run the code, it outputs the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyBuffer_Type
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/multiarray.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/multiarray.so
```

So I went to the Project Interpreter to see if there was an issue with numpy, and the version listed is 1.8.0rc1  which seems peculiar since I don't recall ever seeing a package version with letters in it. I tried updating it, uninstalling and reinstalling, and it still remains as 1.8.0rc1. I have since deleted the project, and copied my python files into a new one to see if that would fix the issue, but it doesn't seem to have worked. Any ideas about what this might be and how to fix it?

EDIT: I am also using a virtual environment for my project
EDIT2: I am using python 3.6, which makes the error more confusing, as it cites issues with Versions/2.7 Not sure if that needs to be addressed in order to fix my initial issue, just putting it out there

Comment: Your second edit is very important. The source of the problem is that python 3.x is being used, but is trying to import a version of numpy that was compiled for python 2.x. The "symbol not found" error refers to how python changed its buffer interface between 2 and 3 (the numpy module is trying to use the buffer interface that is no longer available). I'm making a guess that you changed python versions in your project upgrade. If so, a good place to start would be to delete your virtualenv and rebuild it. Looks like it's trying to use global site packages which isn't a great idea.

Comment: @Dunes thanks for responding. Strangely enough, I have been working with Python 3.6 for quite a while now, and when I switched to the new project, I stayed on the same version of python